# iPhone OS 3.0 Access Clipboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am implementing a custom text editor with syntax highlighting and I would like to integrate it into the OS 3.0 clipboard system. So, my question is, is there a way to programatically set/read the systemwide clipboard?

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: I know people are getting more and more lax about this, but iPhone 3.0 SDK is still under NDA. It's not really appropriate for discussion here yet. The Apple Developer Boards and the Apple 3.0 SDK Documentation would be more appropriate places to investigate the answer to this question.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the NDA, thanks.

Comment: Non-NDA-breaking answer: Yes.

Comment: Ahh I keep forgetting they haven't lifted the NDA. You can see 3.0 information on developer.apple.com without logging in now, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for UIPasteboardNameGeneral.